# How can I call an API function in sequence for all of the elements of an array?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am working with Angular using RxJs, and currently find it very challenging to solve this problem.

I have an array which contains some ids.

```
ids = [1,2,3,4]
```

Then I have an API that can be called with the id param, which deletes the item with the given id from the database:

```
this.controller.deleteItem(id)
```

I want to call this API on every id in the array.

These API calls should strictly happen one after another in a sequential pattern, like

this.controller.deleteItem(1) -> this.controller.deleteItem(2) etc.

After all of the api calls finished, I would like to fetch the data with:

```
this.controller.getData()
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using the [`concat`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat) operator.

First you need to turn the list of IDs into a list of observables, by mapping each item of the array into its corresponding delete action:

```js
const idsToDelete = [1, 2, 3];
const deleteTasks = idsToDelete.map(id => this.controller.deleteItem(id));
```

Then use `concat` to execute the tasks sequentially:

```js
concat(...deleteTasks).subscribe((response) => {
  console.log('deleted', response);
});
```

For getting the data at the end, (assuming that the `getData` method also returns an observable) you can insert it at the end, after the deletes, and only listen for the [`last`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/last) response:

```js
concat(...deleteTasks, this.controller.getData()).pipe(
  // tap((res) => console.log(res)),
  last()
).subscribe((dataAfterDelete) => {
  console.log(dataAfterDelete);
});
```

You can also split these calls if you want to get the chance to perform side effects between the delete operations and the data fetch by using the [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) operator:

```js
const sequentialDelete = concat(...deleteTasks);
sequentialDelete.pipe(
  tap((deleteItemResponse) => {
    console.log('after each item delete', deleteItemResponse);
  }),
  last(),
  tap(() => {
    console.log('after the last item was deleted');
    this.idsToDelete = [];
  }),
  switchMap(() => this.controller.getData())
).subscribe((dataAfterDelete) => {
  console.log(dataAfterDelete);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much it was helpful!

How could I extend this function to be able to call additional APIs after all the deletion finished?

Comment: I updated the answer to include the data fetch at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem.
For future purposes I have one more question:
What if I would like to call some void methods between the deletion and the fetching (or between any observable calls)?

For example:
Delete -> clear array: idsToDelete (void) -> Fetch data

Comment: I updated the answer. You can use [`tap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do) for executing side effects like clearing the array, and other synchronous operations between the async calls.

Answer (score 1):

In simple RxJS way (assumed that both controller functions returns Observables)

```
concat(
 from(ids).pipe(concatMap(id=> this.controller.deleteItem(id))),
 this.controller.getData()
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

What if I would like to include some void functions also between the the the delete-fetch?

For example: Delete -> clear array: idsToDelete (void) -> Fetch data

Comment: Add `of().pipe(tap(()=>idsToDelete = []))` between concat arguments. Or remove each id from array each time emits deleteItem `...deleteItem(id).pipe(tap(()=>this.removeIdFromArray(id)))`. Or collect all return values after `concatMap` with `toArray()` operator then `tap(()=>idsToDelete = [])`

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: NOT SEQUENTIAL

```
forkJoin(
  ids.map<Observable<number>>((id: number) => 
    this.controller.deleteItem(id) )
).subscribe(val => this.controller.getData())
```

[forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin)

> When all observables complete, emit the last emitted value from each.

map your ids array into an Observables array using your "this.controller.deleteItem(id)" then pass that array to forkJoin and subscribe to it. forkJoin does all the deleteItem calls at the same time and emits the output of each when all complete. When all succeed you can call getData()

Comment: This does not guarantee that the actions are going to be executed sequentially. fork join fires all of them at once.

Comment: I completely read over that requirement. Good eye!

Answer (score -2):

```
ids.forEach(async (id) => {
  await this.controller.deleteItem(id);
};
```

Will call your api sequentially.

Comment: This is not the "Angular way" of doing it. In Angular we work with RxJS observables rather than promises.

Comment: is it really useful to use observables rather than promises if it's not a realtime api?

Comment: It's the same thing, just through a different API. I didn't say it was more useful, I just said it was more idiomatic in an Angular project. It's a matter of keeping things consistent and following standards.